# how to place mixed values into alphabetically ordered 2d array python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to read and insert this type of file into 2D array using Python which I never really used.
File format:

```
1 2 cat
2 3 dog
1 3 fly
```

Need to put in a following format:

```
numbers = ['1','2''3']
matrix = [ [ 'unknown', 'cat', 'fly' ],
           [ 'cat', 'unknown', 'dog' ],
           [ 'fly', 'dog', 'unknown']]
```

Currently I only found how to do it for dictionary but I really need to use 2d array.
For dictionary I have:

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
   (key, val) = line.split()
   d[int(key)] = val
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: indentation error in your `for` loop

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the array before you read in the values?

Comment: how are you going from the input to the expected output, can you clarify what you are doing or expecting?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes I do. Its length of the line in file (in this example 3)

Answer (score 0):

We'll read in all the lines as a dictionary of tuples of ints to strings and then we'll initialize the array and then populate it.

```
#build the dict
with open(''file.txt) as infile:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        x, y, z = line.split()
        d[(int(x), int(y))] = z

#initilize array
max_x, max_y = map(max, zip(*d))
arr = []
for i in range(max_y):
    sub = []
    for j in range(max_x): 
        sub.append('')
    arr.append(sub)

#populate the array
for (x, y), item in d.items():
    arr[y-1][x-1] = item
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. But now, if I want to have lets say Strings in place of ints for the numbers = [ 'a', 'b'] list for example and doubles instead of strings in the matrix. That doesn't really work. I suspect it has something to do with indexing arr[y-1][x-1] = item

Comment: In that case you're going to make another dictionary that maps `['a', 'b']` to integers (where they are in the matrix).